# Assign onclick to entire class

Tags: javascript, class, onclick

I'm trying to attach an event handler on all elements with a specific div. I have created a jsfiddle showing an example of my code. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/nw4Xs/

```
var l = document.getElementsByClassName("item").Length;
var foo = function () { alert("foo"); };
for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[i].onclick = foo();
}
```

please no jquery answers

Thanks

Comment: @Mate *"please no jquery answers"*

Comment: onclick should be foo, you're *calling* foo because of the parens. Normally when asking questions you should state what actually happens, e.g., the alert happens too soon, etc.

Comment: (And yeah, what's with the backwards iteration?)

Comment: @DaveNewton Until about 3 years ago, backward iteration was actually more efficient in some browsers.

Comment: @rescue: then, honestly, moss is using some really out-dated tutorials or books, and could stand to be 'corrected' (yeah, it *works*, but it's ugly, and a pain to read).

Comment: @DavidThomas agreed. It's counteracted by the fact that the elements are re-queried upon every iteration too as you said in your answer.

Comment: @rescuecreative Sure, but it's not three years ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I agree. I'm just explaining where that came from. Not saying we should still be doing it.

Comment: The reason I am iterating backwards here is because that's the default way that sublime text writes it. I just used it because I was writing an example and its faster. For a real project I would have written it out correctly myself.

Comment: Also, I realize that calling `getElementsByClassName()` for every element is inefficient, It was not originally written this way, I changed it while debugging to try to pinpoint what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (what `getElementByClassName()` returns) that you want is `length` (lowercase).

To pass a reference to a function, just use its name; don't put parentheses after it. Otherwise you're calling the function and assigning or passing its return value.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var l = items.length;
var foo = function () { alert("foo"); };
for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    items[i].onclick = foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was the most straight forward answer that focused on what was breaking my code. I do appreciate David Thomas's details as well, it was just a lot to digest at the end of the day when I'm just trying to debug some code before bed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest (unless you explicitly need to iterate in reverse):

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('item'),
    l = els.length,
    foo = function () { alert("foo"); };

for (var i = 0; i< l; i++) {
    els[i].onclick = foo;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nw4Xs/4/).

Problems with your code:

```
// 'Length' should be 'length':
var l = document.getElementsByClassName("item").Length;
var foo = function () { alert("foo"); };

// since you're not changing the class-name there's no need to
// go in reverse (it's just confusing to read):
for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // you're re-querying every iteration (plus when you're getting the length), why?
    // keeping the parentheses assigns the (non-existent) return value of the function,
    // instead of binding the function to the 'click' event:
    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[i].onclick = foo();
}
```

Incidentally, you could instead bind the event-handler to the closest ancestor element that wraps all the elements you want to have an effect when they're clicked (note: use the *closest* ancestor that exists in the DOM at the time of event-binding, in this case it's the `body`, because there's no other wrapping elements, in most cases there will be, and the closest should be used to avoid events having to bubble all the way to the 'top'):

```
var bindTarget = document.body, // use the closest wrapping element
    foo = function (e) {
        var e = e || window.event,
            clicked = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (clicked.className.indexOf('item') > -1) {
            alert("foo");
        }
    };

bindTarget.onclick = foo;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nw4Xs/11/).

Comment: +1 for being (for the first several minutes) the only answer that avoids calling `getElementsByClassName` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Array.prototype.forEach` over the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("item")`

```
var foo = function () { alert('foo'); };

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('item'), function ( item ) {
    item.addEventListener('click', foo);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nw4Xs/7/

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in using jQuery, you can write this out a lot simpler. Whilst it's not necessary it may save you a lot of time in the future when you are trying to do harder stuff. At a basic level:

```
function foo...

$(".item").click(foo);
```

This will get all DOM elements with a class of "item" and attach foo to the click event. 
If you're interested, there is lots of documentation and help with using jQuery.

Comment: I quote: *"please no [jQuery] answers"* and, therefore, must ask: ***why would you post this?***

Comment: Apologies...I didn't see that under the code block...please ignore my response